# jQuery Mobile - Ajax Reload from Link or Back Button

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile

Ok, I've tried everything, time to ask the Experts!

I have a multi-page JQM app.

index.html - starts here and pulls a list of projects with Ajax, works great - creates a ListView

streets.html - once you click a ListView item on index.html you come to this page, where it drills down and with Ajax creates a ListView - also works fine

homes.html - once you click a ListView item on streets.html you come to this page, where it drills down again and with Ajax creates a ListView - also works fine

delivery.html - once you click a ListView item on home.html you come to this page, where I have a form to submit data.  Submitting data works fine.  But when I redirect to homes.html I want that Ajax list to reload and it won't.

I've tried links with, changePage, etc.  Can't get it to refresh homes.html

Here is the code for homes.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).delegate('#streetListPageMain', 'pagecreate', function () {


    function getURLParameter(name) {
      return decodeURI(
       (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
       );
    }

    var street = getURLParameter('id');


        $.ajax({
              type: "Get",
              url: "addresses.php",
              data: {"id": street},
              success: function(data) {

                  $('#streetList li').remove();

                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

                    streets = obj.items;

                    $.each(streets, function(index, street) {

                        if (street.serial_number == null) {
                            $('#streetList').append('<li><a href="delivery.html?id=' +  encodeURIComponent(street.addressID) + '"  data-ajax="false">' +
                    '<h4>' +  street.house_number + ' ' +  street.street_name + ' </h4>' +
                    '</li>')
                        } else {
                            $('#streetList').append('<li><a href="delivery.html?id=' +  encodeURIComponent(street.addressID) + '"  data-ajax="false">' +
                    '<h4>' +  street.house_number + ' ' +  street.street_name + ' (completed) </h4>' +
                    '</li>')
                        }

                    });


                     $('#streetList').listview('refresh');
              }
        }); 







});

</script>
</head> 
<body> 


<div id="streetListPageMain" data-role="page" data-cache="false">


    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Streets</h1>
</div>


    <div data-role="content">
         <ul id="streetList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true"></ul>
    </div>      

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So yo add the <li> elements into the streetList <ul> then you redirect the browser to another page?

Comment: `$.mobile.changePage("homes.html", { reloadPage: ture });` make sure that all style sheets and JS libraries are in `<head>` for this page/file.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a typical problem with the back navigation in history. While you move forward to next page you usually pass arguments also and coming back you need to somehow give the same inout data.

I am assuming when you submit the form on delivery.html its via ajax so essentially you are still in delivery html. Now on success of form submit you need to go back to home.html. when you originally cam to home.html you must have passed some parameters in URL based on which home.html decides what to load. Now while going back to home.html you need to pass the same arguments in pagechange.

To solve this problem you need to maintain a stack of history, such thst before you switch the page you should save the data passed to current page on this stack. And when coming back you need to set pop that data from stack. Make use of pagebeforechange event to push and pop from stack. You can check data.options.hashChange to see if you need to push or pop from stack and modify the arguments to pahechange accordingly.

This solution might sound not so clear as a working example would solve your problem easily. However if you spend some time to implement pagebeforechange and write this history stack and invoke pagechange in the end you will find the exercise worth it.

Hope this idea helps.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try

```
$.ajax({url:"your url" + "&time=" + new Date().getTime(),})
```